# Stack on mobile while semi-two-column layout on desktop using bootstrap 5

Tags: flexbox, bootstrap-5

Using Bootstrap 5.2.0's `flex-column flex-md-row` - but I need Section 2 (red) to come in between 1 and 3 in mobile. On desktop it's fine.

[image: Desktop]

[image: Mobile]

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />    
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<title>flex column example</title>

</head>

<body>

<div class="container">

    <div class="d-flex flex-column flex-md-row">

        <div class="d-flex flex-column">
            <div class="bg-warning">
                Section 1: Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
            </div>
            <div class="bg-primary">
                Section 3: Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="d-flex flex-row">
            <div class="bg-danger">
                Section 2: Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </div>
    
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go...

You could use Bootstrap's `order` classes (read more about it [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/flex/#order)), but these are the most helpful when ordering elements that are inside the same wrapper (e.g., inside the same `row`). But there's an alternative solution...

The trick is to create Section 2 twice. Show Section 2 on desktop (add classes `d-md-block d-none`) and show Section 2 on mobile (add classes `d-md-none d-block`).

See the snippet below.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

  <title>flex column example</title>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">

    <div class="d-flex flex-column flex-md-row">

      <div class="d-flex flex-column">
        <div class="bg-warning">
          Section 1: Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen
          book.
        </div>
        <div class="bg-danger d-md-none d-block">
          Section 2: Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen
          book.
        </div>
        <div class="bg-primary">
          Section 3: Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen
          book.
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="d-flex flex-row">
        <div class="bg-danger d-md-block d-none">
          Section 2: Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen
          book.
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution - but I was presented with a cleaner solution using `grid` elsewhere. But this works for `flex` - I guess I have to start migrating to grid wherever possible.

Comment: Yeah, the grid is very nice. Anyway, I usually try not to give advice on possible improvements of the code because of two things: 1) a lot of people don't like YOU suggesting THEM what they should do, 2) there might be a good reason why current code is good enough (you can **always** improve the code, but it's all about how much time you have and/or how much someone is willing to pay).